# Open Windows Surface Camera from C# File Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I have a program that I'm trying to get to work but running into some issues.  I have a File Upload that when I hit it from a desktop it opens File Explorer. So since the Surface has Windows I'd expect it to do the same which it does, however is there a way that I can have it launch the built in camera instead?  If I run the web program from any IOS device it opens the camera up or at least gives the option to.  Anyone know if this is possible?  I downloaded an app in the Windows Store that I saw on a forum but no luck didn't know if I could hard code something.

Found this which I can get it to ask to use camera.. but not sure how to tie that to the file upload http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/accessing-the-device-camera-with-getusermedia

Comment: that would be up to how the Surface and the browser works, I doubt you as the web developer have any influence over it. You didn't have to do anything to get it to work on iOS, so it sounds O/S/device/browser-specific

Comment: @ADyson that's what I was worried about, I just wondered if anyone had ever got it to work.